# How to change outgoing Email address for Workflow SP2013

Tags: workflow, email

My workflow sending mails to several user...
The mail adress from the workflow is "workflow@noreply"...
is it possible to change this to something like "mypersonaladress@domain"?

I checked into the CA but i don't have any options for workflow...

Answer (score 2):

By default you could not change "From" address in SPD workflow.

There are 3rd party workflow extensions that can help you acheive this and the 3rd link provided shows how to set the from address through VS2010.

- http://spdactivities.codeplex.com
- http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint-workflow-activities-kit.aspx
- http://waltermunoz.com/sharepoint-2010/how-to-change-the-from-address-in-a-sharepoint-workflow-2/

Comment: @Milind...k thanks...don't know if i can install pluggins...i'll ask...thank you

Comment: If it works plz mark it as answer

Comment: is the first one only for SP 2007? i'm on 2013

Comment: It have source code. Try to download and upgrade that for 2013